# Carbide / Symbian C++ - Change Application Icon

Tags: c++, symbian, icons, s60, carbide

I am using Carbide (just upgraded to 2.0) to develop an S60 3rd Edition application.

I would like to know the easiest way to change the icon (both the application icon on the device menu **and** the icon at the top left of the main view) because I have the need to skin my application in many different ways as easily as possible.

All my efforts with messing around with .mif files have so far failed. I have a 44x44 .svg icon I made with Illustrator, could someone please help me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the app icon when you run your app use (in the status bar):

```
CEikStatusPane* sp=iEikonEnv->AppUiFactory()->StatusPane();
CAknContextPane* cp=(CAknContextPane *)sp->ControlL(TUid::Uid(EEikStatusPaneUidContext));
_LIT(KContextBitMapFile, "my_bitmap_file.mbm");
CFbsBitmap* bitmap = iEikonEnv->CreateBitmapL(KContextBitMapFile, EMbmBitmap);
CleanupStack::PushL(bitmap);
CFbsBitmap*  bitmapmask = iEikonEnv->CreateBitmapL(KContextBitMapFile, EMbmBitmapMask);
CleanupStack::PushL(bitmapmask);
cp->SetPicture(bitmap, bitmapmask);
CleanupStack::Pop(); // bitmapmask
CleanupStack::Pop(); // bitmap
DrawNow();
```

I'm not aware of any possibility of changing the app icon in the menu list programmatically, other than reinstalling the app with different mif file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the icon in your SIS file and then overinstall it on device then you may have to reboot your device after installation - the application icon is in the Symbian cache and is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS000808_-_Creating_and_adding_an_icon_to_an_S60_3rd_Edition_application

Answer (score 0):

With latest QMake and Qt SDK (4.6.2) you don't need to create any .mif file yourself. An SVG file will do.

For more detailed instructions see: [How to Set Qt Application Icon and Title in Symbian S60](http://qt-mobility.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-set-qt-application-icon-and.html).

Although the article uses Qt Creator, as long as you use QMake then it's the same thing.